# unexpected output in c while returning nothing from an int returning function

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int foo(int a)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=2;i<=a;i++)
        {
            if(i%5==0)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int c = foo(10);
        printf("%d",c);
    }
```

why is 5 getting printed when it is not even mentioned what to return?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int foo(int a)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=2;i<=a;i++)
        {
            return; //no variable is attached with return
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int c = foo(10);
        printf("%d",c);
    }
```

and this one is returning 2. which is the first value of `i` when the loop breaks due to return statement. but where is it mentioned that the function has to return `i`??

Code executed in Linux.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Computer explosion? Computer gives you a cookie? Computer reboot? answer 42? Computer transfers money in your bank account to mine? ??? **All options are equally good.**

Comment: The compiler should have complained about that code. Read the warnings the compiler gives you, they are often just as important to fix as errors (as warnings often idicate things that could become errors at run.-time).

Comment: If its on linux, hoping that you are using a terminal and a gcc compiler. Kindly learn to use gcc options. `-Wall` is a good way to start at it.

Comment: @pmg i was expecting my computer would turn into an atm machine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the compiler gave no warning, that the problem. even i was expecting warning and errors as per theory..
please run the code in your system and see if it does and if you can help me out.

Comment: @shedskin: Please understand that it is your code that you need to look into and not the gcc compiler right now. Of course, learning the gcc compiler messages can really help you understanding waht goes wrong in the code. Read the warnings carefully. Unfortunately this isn't a place to teach you how to use a gcc compiler. I think I'll still toss up [this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/gcc-compiler-options/) to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Not returning a value from a function designed to return an `int` invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen. Quote from the C11 standard:

> **6.9.1 Function definitions**
>
> [...]
>
> 12. If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning an Integer in a method designed to return an Integer, there must be a catch that is returning the last integer created.

If you don't want to return anything, simply return void.

Comment: atleast understand what i am trying to ask.
i know try catch statement and even void. run the code in your system and help me in figuring out the output

Comment: @Method: I believe its not *compulsory* to catch a return value of a function. While, that being true that you return something so that you can catch it and do further processing depending upon the return value.